# How to include associated entities with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

The database schema created has the following relations

[image]

The models used for generating the schema above are

```
 public class Option
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public int ValueId { get; set; }
        public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sku
    {
        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductVariant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int OptionId { get; set; }

        public int ValueId { get; set; }

        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OptionId")]
        public Option Option { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ValueId")]
        public Value Value { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SkuId")]
        public Sku Sku { get; set; }
    }
```

while the product class is

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}
```

How can i load realated entities with this layout?

I tried the following but `Options`, `Values` and `Skus` are not accesible as navigation properties

```
        var products = context.Products
            .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
            .Include(x => x.Options)
            .Include(x => x.Values)
            .Include(x => x.Skus)
```

What changes should i make?

Comment: Check `ThenInclude`. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack navigation property in your product class:

```
public IEnumerable<Sku> Skus { get; set; }
```

And you need to use .ThenInclude instead of .Include when you are getting nested entities. It would be:

```
var products = context.Products
               .Include(x => x.Skus)
               .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
                   .ThenInclude(ProductVariants => ProductVariants.Options)
               .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
                   .ThenInclude(ProductVariants => ProductVariants.Values)
```